# Updating Existing Entity in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm using JPA with Hibernate 5.2.10.Final (Oracle database), and deploying on Weblogic 12.2.1.

Let's say I have 2 tables: `Customer` and `LastActivity`:

```
Customer {
  id int,
  name String,
  last_activity_id int not null
}

LastActivity {
  id int,
  customerName String,
  date Date
}
```

There is a `One to Many` relationship: a `Customer` has a single `Activity` and one `Activity` has many `Customers`.

I have a functionality of adding a `Customer`, when it happens the record in `LastActivity` table must be created if it doesn't exist for that `Customer`, otherwise the date must be updated.

My code looks like this (simplified for the purpose of the question):

```
public Response createCustomer(Request request) {
  String name = request.getName();
  Customer customer = new Customer(name);
  LastActivity activity = activityDao.findByCustomerName(name)
      .orElseGet(LastActivity.from(name));
  activity.setDate(ZonedDateTime.now());
  customer.setActivity(activityDao.update(activity));
  return Response.of(customer);
}
```

My `update` method is straightforward:

```
return entityManager.merge(entity);
```

When I add a new `Customer` and an `Activity` that doesn't exist yet ― it is created correctly with the date I specified. The problem is when the activity already exists ― the update doesn't happen. In the logs there is just a select query on `Activities` table, then correct insert on `Customers` table, but the date is old.

Some things I tried:

```
public T update(T entity) {
  EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
  T updated = manager.contains(entity) ? entity : manager.persist(entity);
  manager.flush();
  return updated;
}
```

Same thing, nothing changed. Also:

- Without flushing
- Doing `merge` instead of just returning entity when contains returns true
- Just a flush by itself
- Nothing since the entity is "attached"

Tried adding `CascadeType.MERGE`...still nothing. Only thing that worked was this:

```
public T update(T entity) {
  EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();
  manager.detach(entity);
  return manager.merge(entity);
}
```

It did what I wanted it to do, but it added extra select query on `Activity` table (simply by `ID`, but still, I would like to avoid that).

I actually managed to "solve" the problem by using `CriteriaUpdate`, but I don't like this and it seems like I lack of some fundamental knowledge about JPA/Hibernate so I don't just want to leave it like this.

Comment: relation between seems not elegant (on name), and lead to hidden errors

Comment: reverse 'relation' by int key totally has nothing to JPA style